# React checkbox state with id or other attributes instead of name

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox

In `react`, is it possible to manage the state of multiple checkboxes with `id` attribute or other attributes such as `data-*`?

For the moment all I'm using is the `name` attribute, however in my project I need to use the `id` or preferably `data-*` due to the complexity of the project, but it seems that in `react` it's isn't possible.

Or am I not understanding in?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import someData from './someData'

function Checkbox({ name, id, label, checked, onChange }) {
  return (
    <span>
      <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        name={name} 
        id={id} 
        checked={checked} 
        onChange={onChange} 
      />
      <span>{label}</span>
    </span>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState()

  const onCheckboxChange = event => {
    const target = event.currentTarget;
    const name = target.name
    const id = target.id;
    const checked = target.checked;

    setIsChecked({
      ...isChecked,
      [id]: checked // using "id" seems to not work here.
    })
  }

  return (
    someData.map(item => {
      return (
        <Checkbox
          name={item.name}
          id={item.id}
          label={item.name}
          onChange={onCheckboxChange}
          checked={isChecked}
        />
      );
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem to do what you need in React whatsoever.

You may use [dataset API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) to access `data-*` attributes values to update your state on checkbox change (e.g. if you assign `data-chkboxname` attribute to your checkbox):

```
onCheckboxChange = ({target:{checked, dataset:{chkboxname}}}) => {
          setIsChecked({
            ...isChecked,
            [chkboxname]: checked
          })
        }
```

Following is a quick proof-of-a-concept live-demo:

```js
const { useState } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
      
const App = () => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState({}),
        onCheckboxChange = ({target:{checked, dataset:{chkboxname}}}) => {
          setIsChecked({
            ...isChecked,
            [chkboxname]: checked
          })
        },
        onFormSubmit = e => {
          e.preventDefault()
          console.log(isChecked)
        }
        
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
    {
      ['chckbox1', 'chckbox2', 'chckbox3'].map(checkbox => (
        <label key={checkbox}>
          {checkbox}
          <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            data-chkboxname={checkbox}
            onChange={onCheckboxChange}
            checked={isChecked[checkbox]}
          />
        </label>
      ))
    }
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
   </form>
  )        
}

render (
  <App />,
  rootNode
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
return someData.map((item) => {
    return (
      <Checkbox
        name={item.name}
        id={item.id}
        label={item.name}
        checked={item.checked}
      />
    );
  });
```